# convert a colum to different format

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column with name 'DateInput' have value: as

```
04/01/2014
03/21/2014
03/20/2014
--mm/dd/yyyy
```

So I want to change it to dd/mm/yy

```
01/04/2014
21/03/2014
20/03/2014
```

Do it with update statement?
I try with my code:

```
update dondh
set DateInput = CONVERT(nvarchar(50),DateInput,103)
```

But I meet a error:

The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Pls help me fix this problem.

Comment: Well what is the actual type of the column? It should be `date`, which doesn't *have* a text format in terms of storage, any more than integer values are stored as "decimal" or "hex"...

Comment: Oracle does not have a `convert` function. Are you sure you are using Oracle? The error message does not sound like it is.

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
update dondh set DateInput = to_char(to_date(DateInput, 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

But as Jon says, date columns should be date, not strings...

Answer (score -1):

```
Update table 
Set column = to_char(to_date(column,'mm/dd/yyyy'),'dd/mm/yy');
```

This should work if its Oracle and column data type in NOT date. If its date, then you can skip `to_date` function.

Cheers